# Howto use Maven Cargo Plugin to deploy a Web Application Bundle (WAB, OSGI + JavaEE) into Glassfish 3.x

Tags: maven, glassfish, osgi, cargo, wab

I'm trying to use the Maven Cargo Plugin to deploy a set of OSGI bundles and an hybrid application .war (Webapplication with Restservice which uses OSGI) also called a Web Application Bundle (or WAB) (e.g. see https://glassfish.java.net/public/GF-OSGi-Features.pdf).

Deploying of OSGI bundles into a Glassfish 3.1.x works fine, but I haven't found a way to deploy the Web Application Bundle.

It's packaging is "war", but I have to deploy it as OSGI bundle. So how can I tell this the Cargo Plugin?

The maven configuration I tried to use:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <wait>false</wait>

      <container>
        <containerId>glassfish3x</containerId>
        <home>${glassfish.home}</home>
        <type>installed</type>
      </container>
      <configuration>
        <type>existing</type>
        <home>${glassfish.home}</home>
        <properties>
          <cargo.hostname>localhost</cargo.hostname>
          <cargo.rmi.port>4848</cargo.rmi.port>
          <cargo.domain.name>${glassfish.domain}</cargo.domain.name>
        </properties>
      </configuration>
      <deployables>
        <deployable>
          <groupId>com.acme.rest</groupId>
          <artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
          <type>bundle</type>
        </deployable>
      </deployables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But the following error shows up:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:redeploy (default-cli) on project rest-api: Artifact [com.acme.rest:rest-api:bundle] is not a dependency of the project. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:redeploy (default-cli) on project rest-api: Artifact [com.acme.rest:rest-api:bundle] is not a dependency of the project.

Deploying as component type "web" works, but then I can't use the OSGI bundles...

Does anybody have experience with deploying Web Application Bundle and OSGI bundles?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about cargo plugin, but to deploy a wab using asadmin client, one has to pass a --type=osgi option as shown below:

asadmin deploy --type=osgi foo.war

So, see if you can configure cargo plugin to pass this option.

Sahoo

Comment: Your are right, but the question is how to pass this parameter!
From analyzing the cargo sources, I found out, that the type is set to "osgi" exactly when the packaging type of the module is "bundle", but in an hybrid application the packaging type is "war".

Answer (score 0):

The trick is :

```
<deployable>
  <groupId>com.acme.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
  <type>war</type>
  <implementation>org.codehaus.cargo.container.deployable.Bundle</implementation>
</deployable>
```

You still have a WAR artifact, but Bundle will trick Cargo to deploy it as OSGi.

Answer (score 0):

Try using version `1.4.7` which added support for sending `asadmin` params in conjunction with the param that @Sahoo mentioned.

```
<cargo.glassfish.deploy.arg.1>--type=osgi foo.war</cargo.glassfish.deploy.arg.1>
```

**Allow passing extra parameters for glassfish deployment**
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-1245